# Recursive proof that $n^n \geq n!$

Tags: induction

So I'm trying to prove, by induction, that
$$ n^n \geq n!, \forall n\geq1$$

Base case:

$$ \text{For } n=1, 1^1 = 1 \geq 1 = 1!$$

Hypothesis:

$$ n^n \geq n!$$

Step:

$$ \text{Trying to prove: } n^{n+1} \geq (n+1)! $$

Now, somewhere around here I get some contradicting things. For example, if I start from the right side I get:

$$ (n+1)! = (n+1)\cdot n! \leq (n+1)\cdot n^n = n\cdot n^n + n^n = n^{n+1} + n^n$$

Based on this I would need $n^{n+1} + n^n$ to be less than or equal to $n^{n+1}$, which is certainly not true. Something similar happens when I go the other way.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here?
Thanks.

Comment: "Trying to prove: $n^{n+1} \geq (n+1)!$" No: Trying to prove: $(n+1)^{n+1} \geq (n+1)!$

Comment: Well, now I feel stupid. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have to prove this with induction? I think you could just write out what the two terms mean, and you will see that the hypothesis is true.

Comment: Indeed induction is not at all the most direct route here.

Comment: "Well, now I feel stupid." Who never does? "Thanks." You are welcome.

Comment: You forget $n+1$ in the base... of your 1 step...

Comment: None of the existing answers have pointed out that your getting contradiction does not imply a problem. In fact, $n^{n+1}$ **IS greater than** $(n+1)!$ for every $n ≥ 2$, which is immediately obvious from $n^3 > 1·2·(n+1)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$(n+1)! = (n+1)\cdot n! \leq (n+1)\cdot n^n$ by induction hypothesis, and
$(n+1)\cdot n^n\leq (n+1)\cdot (n+1)^n = (n+1)^{n+1}$. Done.

Comment: I don't know why, but your answer shows"$\leq (n+1) by \cdot n^n$" even though you did not type it that way.

Answer (score 7):

You should try to prove that $$(n+1)^{n+1} \ge (n+1)!$$

\begin{align}
(n+1)^{n+1} &= (n+1) (n+1)^n\\
&\ge(n+1)n^n 
\end{align}

Now use induction hypothesis.

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to prove :

$$(n+1)^{n+1} \geq (n+1)!$$

Not :

$$n^{n+1} \geq (n+1)!$$

Comment: This isn't an answer! Can you show some steps ?

Comment: @ArchisWelankar I am answering his question. There is nothing to add. And you downvote, what a ridiculous behaviour.

Answer (score 5):

You need to show that $(n+1)^{n+1} \geq (n+1)!$, not that $n^{n+1} \geq (n+1)!$.

Here are some similar questions asked before: you can check your work against any of them if you'd like.

- [Induction Proof $n! < n^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1500667/279515)
- [Show that $n!<n^n $ where $n>1$ and is a Positive Integer](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1046979/279515)
- [Proof of $\forall n \in \Bbb N$, $n > 2 \implies n! < n^n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/876626/279515)

For future reference, [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz) is an excellent resource to search for similar questions (much better than the SE functionality itself). All the best.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative:
$$
n! = \underbrace{{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}}_{n\ \text{times}} \\
n^n = \underbrace{n \cdot n\cdot n \dots n}_{n\ \text{times}}
$$

Note that:
$$
{n! \over n^n} = \frac{n(n-1)(n-2)\cdots 3\cdot 2\cdot 1}{n \cdot n\cdot n \dots n} = \\
= \frac{n}{n} \cdot  \frac{n-1}{n} \cdot \frac{n-2}{n} \cdots  \frac{2}{n} \cdot  \frac{1}{n}
$$

Now note that for any $n \ge 2$:
$$
\frac{n!}{n^n} < 1
$$